# Flutter problemas con el Login de Google

Tags: firebase, google-api, flutter, dart

Buen día comunidad necesito de su apoyo, estoy desarrollando una App con flutter en lo cual estoy usando la autenticación con google y Firebase, estoy siguiendo una documentación en el siguiente link [Flutter: Implementación de inicio de sesión de Google](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-implementing-google-sign-in-71888bca24ed)

en lo cual la documentación hace un énfasis lineas abajo sobre una excepción `PlatformException` y su solución, y bueno seguí la documentación detalladamente pero a pesar de eso recibo la excepción, agrego la excepción que recibo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

archivo pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.4
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+8
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+8
  http: ^0.12.0+2
```

archivo android/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

archivo android/app/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

archivo login.dart

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';

}

void signOutGoogle() async {
  await _googleSignIn.signOut();
  print("USER SIGN OUT");
}
```

Vista de la localización del archivo google-services.json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vista de las creedenciales:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vista de console.google agregando los dominios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recalcar que también habilite la autenticación en el proyecto de firebase y también habilite los métodos de sesión de google, correo electrónico y opcional(Google Play).

Agrego la descripción de la aplicación Android de Firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es un error que hasta ahora no encuentro alguna solución espero de su gran ayuda, amigos.

Comment: Me sigue arrojando la misma excepción, amigo a pesar de agregar el package firebase_core

Comment: Por lo que veo la configuración esta bien en lo que respecta a dependencias y la función para iniciar sesión con google. El problema esta en la clave SHA1 que agregaste a la app en la consola de firebase que puede estar mal o el googleservice.json. Te recomendaria volver a generar el SHA1 o volver a bajar el archivo googleservices.json con eso va a funcionar correctamente. Tambien podes abrir el json de los servicios y ver que este todo como corresponde.

Answer (score 1):

Os lo pongo por si ayuda, ya que yo me volví loco hasta que lo encontré.
Lo que está claro es que el error 10, se refiere a una mala configuración de credenciales.

1. Primero, consigue tus claves SHA-1 para el modo debug:

   Click en Gradle (En el panel derecho)
   Click en Tasks
   Click en Android
   Doble Click en signingReport (En la parte inferior verás las claves.)
2. Añadir los credenciales a la API también

   Ve a https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
   Crea nuevo OAuth Client ID
   Name : Cliente Android pruebas
   Signing-certificate fingerprint : Copiar y pegar tu clave SHA-1
   Poner el nombre del paquete
3. Añadir la clave al proyecto de Firebase :

   Ir a la configuración del proyecto y añadir el certificado SHA

   Volver a descargar el archivo google-services.json y cargarlo en el proyecto Android en la carpeta app.

Aquí hay un hilo en inglés que lo describe muy bien: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437678/why-do-i-get-com-google-android-gms-common-api-apiexception-10

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que uses un bloque try catch para capturar de mejor manera el error y saber por qué esta fallando, te pongo un ejemplo:

```
Future<FirebaseUser> signInGoogle() async {
  try {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await _gSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication authentication =
      await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: authentication.accessToken,
      idToken: authentication.idToken);

    FirebaseUser user = await _fAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
    new User(name: user.displayName, photoUrl: user.photoUrl, uid: user.uid);
    return user;
    } catch (err) {
        print(err);
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Amigo acabo de corregir la imagen del error, con el mensaje de la excepción

Answer (score 0):

Buenas pude solucionar mi problema partiendo de un error garrafal mío, como se podrá notar en la primera imagen de mi pregunta, me muestra la siguiente Excepción: `com.google.android.gms.common.api.apiexception: 10` esta excepción se basa con **Firebase** y las **huellas digitales SHA**, en base a ese problema llegue a un tutorial que generaba automaticamente un **KEY**, a la vez seguía un articulo y un video tutorial, pero mas me inclinaba en la explicación del video tutorial.

Imagen de mi key generada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema era que a través de tener problema tras problema no tenia conciencia lo que realmente tenia que solucionar, este era el problema ya que en este Articulo que coloque en la pregunta [flutter-implementing-google-sign-in](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-implementing-google-sign-in-71888bca24ed) me decia que que tenia que generar mi SHA a través de esta ruta user.android\debug.keystore, y desde ahi puedo obtener SHA1. y luego agregarlo a mi proyecto en Firebase, desde mi funciona todo correctamente.